# TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keep_date_col'

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to combine the year, month, day and the hour in one cell. However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keep_date_col'
```

The code that produces this error:

```py
def convert_to_date(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x,'%Y %m %d %H')
aq_df = pd.read_excel('D:\\data.xlsx', parse_dates = [['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour']], date_parser = convert_to_date, keep_date_col = True)
```

Comment: `keep_date_col` parameter is available in `pd.read_csv` and not in `pd.read_excel`.

Comment: Yes, there isn't a keep_date_col param for that function. But I just write this comment to recommend you to use Unix Epoch timestamp instead of strings and not to use pandas.read_excel. read_excel and to_excel functions are mostly unstable. If it isn't necessary to use Excel, use csv instead.

Comment: Dear sir/madam, Your suggestion to work with CSV file did work. Looking forward to a similar kind of help in near future. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
pandas.read_excel(io, sheet_name=0, header=0, names=None, index_col=None, usecols=None, squeeze=False, dtype=None, engine=None, converters=None, true_values=None, false_values=None, skiprows=None, nrows=None, na_values=None, keep_default_na=True, na_filter=True, verbose=False, parse_dates=False, date_parser=None, thousands=None, comment=None, skipfooter=0, convert_float=True, mangle_dupe_cols=True, storage_options=None)[source]
```

These are the read_excel arguments. I do not see `keep_data_col` in here.

Comment: working with CSV file instead of excel did help. thank you.